# Server Side Pagination + jQuery Question

Tags: ajax, jquery, pagination

I have yet to come across a good tutorial that explains how to load records from a database and spit them out using jQuery Ajax and also display pagination navigation.

Example Page

- Apple
- Banana
- Pear
- Grapes

(Pagination Nav)
[First Page] [Prev Page] [5] [6] [7] [Next Page] [Last Page]

In my head I think it works like this.

1. User loads home page. Home page by
   default spits out records with at
   the first offset and with a
   specified results per page (e.g.
   LIMIT 0,10)
2. Serverside script queries count of
   records, extrapolates number of
   pages to navigate by using results
   per page.
3. Serverside script echoes a
   navigation panel based on current
   page.
4. jQuery listens for click events on
   navigation panel, uses get to fetch
   the content and sets html of content
   container.

I also want the URL of the site to change in case anyone refreshes the page (to obviously display the desired result).

How can this be done?

Comment: Well this **completely** depends on your server-side framework. The server's the thing that has to tell the page how many total pages there are, how many total records there are (probably, because you probably want to show that), and what the current page is. Exactly how that's communicated can vary all over the map.  Where you say, "echoes a navigation panel", that basically covers it. What does that look like? Well it's up to your server.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [dataTables](http://datatables.net/examples/), a jQuery plugin that covers exactly what your talking about look for server-side procesing